# php5 Mcrypt Refusing to be installed for Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, mcrypt

I've been trying to get MCRYPT to install for the past hour - To no avail

Reply :

php5-mcrypt: Depends: phpapi-20090626

Php version :PHP Version 5.4.6-2~lucid+1
Ubuntu 10.04
NGINX web server

Comment: How are you enabling this extension? it looks like you have a version mismatch

Comment: Didnt enable anything yet - I'm still trying to download it

Comment: apt-get install php5-mcrypt?

Comment: Yes , That's all till now

Comment: So what is you issue exactly? What do you mean with download? Do you get any errors? What does `php -m` tell you? You need to give a bit more information.

Comment: Did you uncomment the line `;extension=mcrypt.so`?

Comment: When I download the php5-mcrypt module it refuses , stating the above. Yes I added the extension = mcrypt.so , but what use is it if the libary is not installed. php-m shows that the libary is not installed

Comment: A quick search brings you to http://askubuntu.com/questions/19700/broken-packages-php-apc-depends-phpapi-20090626lfs Have you tried the accepted answer here?

Comment: @ ben , no it didnt work - I got  php5-cgi: Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.22) but 5.4.6-2~lucid+1 is to be installed

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are two things that made me unable to install MCRYPT

1) no support for this version of php

2) MYCRYPT has a conflict with SlimFramework , which I use